# Getting an 'Intent Disambiguation' Error when deploying a bot with a NEW NLP setup to the next sandbox

Tags: einstein, deployment-error, bot

We recently deployed NLP to our existing Bot in a sandbox - we've created an intent set, loaded the intent set with utterances, turned on einstein and added the intent set to the different dialogs we need it in, and we modelled the Bot.  She is working wonderfully in the initial sandbox we created her in.  When we try to deploy her to a different sandbox we are deploying the Bot, the Bot version, the intent set and a flow that we created and added to her during this change.  We are getting the following error and I don't know how to resolve it.  Does anyone have experience with this and know what I can do?

**Error: Error parsing file: Element {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}intentDisambiguationEnabled invalid at this location in type BotVersion**

I've tried turning off the NLP in all the dialogs prior to deployment in case that was the cause.  It didn't change the outcome. Still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error when trying to push the a new version of the Einstein bot from a sandbox to production.

I believe it might be to do with the fact the our sandboxes are on the Summer 23' pre-release whilst our production org is on the Spring 23'release. My guess is there has been some changes in the backend which aren't compatible with the different versions.

I was able to push my bot through the pipeline with no issue as they're all on Summer 23' but have hit this snag with trying to push it to Production, meaning I'll have to manually make my changes.

Hope this helps!